# Responsive reorganizing of divs in DOM

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tailwind-css

My project uses Tailwind + Vue 2. I'm using Vue to iterate through a list and show multiple rows. Each row starts collapsed and has the option to be expanded.

There are 3 visible and 1 hidden div element in each collapsed row. When expanded, the hidden div is made visible. I'm looking to take 2 of the visible div elements from each row and move them into the hidden dropdown div when on mobile. When expanded on mobile, I expect the moved elements to be visible. I also want them to move back when switching from mobile to desktop view.

The expected behavior is as follows:

- On desktop, collapsed, the toggle switch and message are displayed.
- On desktop, expanded, the toggle switch and message are displayed, does not change location.
- On mobile, collapsed, the toggle switch and message are NOT displayed, and are instead moved into the collapsed (hidden) div.
- On mobile, expanded, the toggle switch and message are displayed.

This photo demonstrates what I'm looking to achieve.

[image: demo]

These have been my attempts so far:

1. **CSS / Duplicate** - Duplicate the element. Make one hidden on mobile and visible on desktop, and the other visible on mobile and hidden on desktop. Although not a clean way of doing this, it appears to work -- until I use the toggle switch. It loses functionality (I assume since it's being repeated).
2. **Tailwind/CSS `order`** - As the utility name suggests, the order on the page will indeed change, but this will not move the desired elements into a hidden element; rather move it above/below the hidden element.
3. **Vue Teleport** - This is for Vue 3, but there are packages available for Vue 2, such as `portal-vue`. I tried it, and since the rows are being iterated, all of the elements end up shoved in the last row's expanded view. I would prefer not to use a package.
4. **Javascript** - Similar to teleport/portal: tag divs "move-from" and "move-to" and find them with `getElementsByClassName`. Iterate through each `move-me` and `dropdown` tag (there are 2 `move-me` tags for every single `dropdown` tag). Add event listener for window resize and check to see if page width is < 768. The problem with this is, like teleport/portal, it also stuffs all the elements into the last row's expanded view.

```
if (this.width < 768) {
  const moveMeParent = document.getElementsByClassName('move-me') // there are 20 of these
  const dropdownParent = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown') // there are 10 of these
  for (let i = 0; i < dropdownParent.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      dropdownParent[i].appendChild(moveMeParent[0])
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: css `order` property won't work because I assume you have nesting html here. The duplicating solution should work nicely though, with a `display: none` on mobile/desktop. What's the problems you encountered with this?

Comment: @Kapcash The toggle switch component does not update its status until the page is refreshed.

Comment: So that's another problem :) The v-model variable has to be the same between the two clones, so they both update when the other change.

Comment: @Kapcash ahhh gotcha, it was indeed a separate problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to provide an anwser in order to mark this as solved:

When you need a different layout (i.e. html markup) between desktop & mobile, there are a few solutions there:

1. **Duplicating the elements** so they are in both the desktop & mobile position in the DOM. **Use CSS** to hide one or the other with media queries.

+ Pros: easy to setup, works great for SSR, no js needed.
- Cons: adds additional markup to the DOM, which can slow down the page render if done too many times.

> That's the solution I advise in OP's case

2. Using javascript to **dynamically render the components** on a place or another. In vue, that means using `v-if="isMobile"`.

+ Pros: avoid ghost markup in the DOM as in solution 1.
- Cons: causes flickering on SSR (it renders as desktop or mobile on the server, then updates to another layout when hydrated).

3. On some cases, use **css only to move** your element. Like `flex-direction: row-reverse` or `order: n`.

+ Pros: easy to setup, no js needed.
- Cons: Only works for siblings elements.